# export data from dot net nuke

Tags: export, dotnetnuke

I'm migrating some data from DNN to another platform, and need a way to extract database tables one by one in some useful format like XML, CSV etc.

Is there a way to dump and export the whole database or just a few tables at a time?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a SQL server database, all the standard SQL server tools will work (e.g. [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(SQL.80).aspx) ).

Also many DNN modules explicitly support import/export of their content.

Comment: Thanks. That was the clue I needed. For those who follow: I found an Import Export Data wizard in the SQL Server folder. Exporting multiple tables to Excel seemed to have the least problems